# Why doesn't the Fourth Line End With "Arnie"?

Tags: java, constructor

I am "learning Java" using a tutorial.  One of the lessons involves constructors calling constructors.
After the lesson I did some playing around doing "strange stuff" and I can't figure out what is happening.
I attached an image file captured from the Eclipse screen. (don't be hating).
I thought that would be better because it shows the output screen.
I would expect "name" to be "Arnie" the first time it is printed in the second constructor.

Why is it "Bertie"?

```
class Machine {
    private String name;
    private int code;

    public Machine() {
        this("Arnie", 0);
        System.out.println("First constructor running: " + name);
    }

    public Machine(String name) {
        this("Arnie", 0);
        System.out.println("Second constructor running before 'this.name': " + name);
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("Second constructor running after 'this.name': " + name);
    }

    public Machine(String name, int code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        System.out.println("Third constructor running: " + name + " " + code);
    }
}

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine machine1 = new Machine();
        Machine machine2 = new Machine("Bertie");
        Machine machine3 = new Machine("Chalkie", 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code not a picture of code.

Comment: No one is "hating", but please provide code, not a screenshot. A screenshot is not helpful. It's not searchable, it cannot be read by people with visual impairments who use screenreaders, it's textual contents won't be indexed by search engines, and it can't be copied which makes it unnecessarily hard to try to run and debug your code.

Comment: As I tried to explain in my post I was using an image because it included the output window and I wanted to refer to it.  I also saw that posting code didn't show the line numbers and I felt I might have to refer to line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It is printing the `name` variable that is passed in to the constructor. Leaving everything the same, you would see "Artie" if you were to change `name` to `this.name`.

Comment: Now I get it.  When Machine2 is created the "name" in line 10 is equal to Bertie.  Line 11 changes the "name" in line 2 to Artie (actually it is Artie already from line 6) but I am printing the "name" passed in line 10.  I know using "name" so much is bad practice but I was expanding on a lesson and it has helped me understand.  But I am sure this will burn me a few times when I start to code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the constructor that takes the `name` argument is shadowing the property String `name`.  Either change constructor argument to something other than `name`, or change lines 12 and 14 to be `this.name`.

Comment: Now I get it.  When Machine2 is created the "name" in line 10 is equal to Bertie.  Line 11 changes the "name" in line 2 to Artie (actually it is Artie already from line 6) but I am printing the "name" passed in line 10.  I know using "name" so much is bad practice but I was expanding on a lesson and it has helped me understand.  But I am sure this will burn me a few times when I start to code.